# Is there a story where the sages taught that Cain was the son of the Satan

Tags: midrash

Do the sages teach that Cain came from the union from Eve and The Satan?

Comment: The Gemara shabbos 145B-146A mentions the Union (see rashi). This article https://www.etzion.org.il/en/tanakh/torah/sefer-bereishit/parashat-bereishit/bereishit-snakes-sin-and-its-punishment posits that Cain was born from that Union but I don’t think this is who you mean by sages

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/124455/when-was-hevel-born/124461#124461. Ask those sages send to say he was born through Adam

Comment: Thank you sir, I appreciate it

Comment: See the following answer starting at the paragraph discussing the Nachash. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/133804/7303

Comment: Building on the gemara in shabbos above, the Zohar says from this impurity that the snake placed in her from their union, Cain was born

Comment: וּמֵהַהִיא זוּהֲמָא נָפַק קַיִן וְקָטַל לְהֶבֶל רוֹעֵה צֹאן

Answer (score 0):

Yes, however, check out the Guide for the Perplexed, which explains the whole "lilith" thing and "snake poison" thing to be a metaphor for ignorance. Search sefaria for "cain" in the guide for the perplexed to find it.

The Zohar explains that there was a general improvement until the revelation at Sinai. Search the zohar for "seth" or "Shet" to find it, should be in parshat bereshit.

Comment: You can’t just answer “yes” without saying where.