# What exactly was Adam and Chava's sin?

Tags: sin, parashat-bereishit, adam

Bereshit 2:9-10 tells that HaShem made to spring up every tree (in Gan Eden) pleasing to the sight, and tov for food and the Etz HaChayim (Tree of Life) also in the midst of Gan Eden, and the Etz HaDa’as Tov v’Rah (knowledge of good and bad). HaShem tells (2:16) Adam explicitly not to eat from the fruit of the tree of good and bad. The rest is history because Adam did eat of it and therefore sinned.

But what exactly was the sin? To disobey, eat, listen to the snake?

Comment: Rav Dessler has a great essay on this i  Michtav MiEliyahu

Comment: Partial duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41106/472 (this addresses their culpability but not what precisely the sin was).

Comment: @MonicaCellio removed. No reason to have two questions here, one of which is answered elsewhere on-site already.

Comment: could you tell me where please? i still want to know what caused them to sin.

Comment: J.Levi, I saw your comment by chance; if you want to comment so I'm more likely to see it, use `@msh210` in your comment. It's in [the post that @MonicaCellio linked to](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41106).

Comment: Is your question what the _act_ of the sin was, or something else?

Comment: both committed 2 sins. Chava's second sin was tempting her husband. Adam's was telling Lashon Hara on Chava. Not sure you can tell lashon hara about a serpent so Chava probably not guilty on that but she should have admitted her sin.

Comment: This is an incredibly difficult question to answer precisely and correctly. Knowing the answer to this question probably requires understanding the entire Torah.

Answer (score 0):

The type of sin of Adam and Chava is still a sin to this day. Rabbi Shneur Zalman of Liadi explains in Likutei Amarim regarding permissible food that at the moment one indulges in a desire simply to satisfy the craving of ones body, the “kelipas nogah”(literally “shell that shines”) representing the positive potential hidden in that moment is lowered into the “shalosh kelipos hatemeos” (literally “three shells of impurity”) indicating the wickedness of the person in that moment. [Likutei Amarim chapter 7](https://www.chabad.org/library/tanya/tanya_cdo/aid/7886/jewish/Chapter-7.htm) In the case of Adam and Chava eating from the tree wasn’t even a permissible pleasure. The first sin seems to be a series of  events connected to pleasure: first Adam and Chava where engaged in pleasure that was holy for the sake of propagating. Later they took their pleasurable pursuits a bit too far in an attempt to become their own deities as Rashi explains in Genesis 3:5. This type of arrogance is also a modern day sin. Once they came off their high horse and realized that they neglected the one thing their creator and benefactor requested of them they felt shame, guilt and fear. See the second Rashi on Genesis 3:7 [chapter three of Genesis with Rashi’s commentary](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-3.htm)

Comment: @Ionlyknowgensis - welcome to Mi Yodeya! Your answers would do much better if 1) you linked the sources so ppl can see them in context, 2) Providing quotes where the key points are made, and 3) Provide translation even for the small terms like "klipas nogah" for those who are not familiar with either Hebrew or the concepts can more readily understand. Hatzlocho!

Comment: I will try to touch it up.

Answer (score 0):

Rushing. דחיקת השעה.
It is the source and the root of all kilkulim and chataim, all fails.  I heard this in a tape of R Isaac Bezançon circa 2000, based on L. Moharan.

They were to eat of it for Friday night but they couldn't wait - Midrash.

Comment: The punishment being an interminable exercise in patience

Comment: Oyyyyyyy Nanach good one @schmosel