# How did adam an eve sin before the existence of the evil inclination?

Tags: adam, evil-inclination

If people only sin because the evil inclination compells them to sin, how then did adam and eve sin before the evil inclination was in existence?

Comment: The evil inclination was extant as an external force. The behavior made it internal to mankind. It didn't call it into existence.

Comment: @danno, so during that interaction with the snake, Adam and Eve got a taste of free will?

Comment: @AniYodea Yes. Since this was during the six days of creation, this allowed Adam and Chava to establish how free will would work according to the "laws of nature". Had they refrained (of their free will) from eating the fruit, that would have established a different type choice between "good" and "evil". That is why there is a medrash that they would have been allowed to eat from the fruit **after** shabbos.

Comment: @sabbahillel, which medrash?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/41106

Comment: For example Rabbi Brasil in http://blog.shabbat.com/parshas-ki-savoh-al-hamichya-and-the-middah-of-patience-by-rav-shmuel-brazil/ says Their failing was that they did not possess the patience to wait until Shabbos to eat from the Aitz Hadaas which then would have been permitted. This is hinted in the passuk ומעץ הדעת טוב (Bereishis 2,17) is gematriah שבת

Comment: Related answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/130262/7303