# Adam and the tree of life?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, death, parashat-bereishit, trees, adam

I have been considering Adam and what G-d said about Adam pertaining to the tree of life directly after the fall. After Adam had transgressed, G-d commanded that the tree of life be withheld from him that he may not partake of its fruit and become immortal.

[Bereshis 3:22](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8167#v=22) (Genesis 3:22):

> And Hashem Elohim said, See, HaAdam is become like one of Us, knowing
>   tov v’rah; and now, lest he put forth his yad, and take also of HaEtz
>   HaChayyim, and eat, and chai l’olam (live forever);

What would have happened if Adam would have eaten from the tree of life after he had already "fallen", would he have lived forever as a physical immortal in his "fallen" state?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26631/472

Comment: Whose translation is that? ....if it's not your's, some attribution would be nice.

Comment: @Shokhet Even if it is his he can attribute it as such

Comment: @DoubleAA But of course. ....I was considering replacing it with the Chabad translation, to match the link, but I figured that would be too much, given that he didn't choose that link (according to revision history). What do you think?

Comment: @Shokhet the flavor of the translation reminds me of some missionary sites. They tend to deliberately transliterate some words instead of translating them in order to try to give an impression of "knowing" the torah. Similarly the use of the term "fall" is similar. I do not know if that is where eliyah got the translation or not. The 11 questions asked also give an impression, but that may be because of the translation in this question.

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/121945

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in principle yes, as the verse you quoted says. But God has foresight and knows how to plan things so that it never happens. It's kind of like playing chess with a chess grandmaster. Although, you have free will, he can nevertheless force you into any situation he wants.

How much more so for God who knows ahead of time what you will think and do, that He can plan things ahead of time or even put thoughts in your head so as to direct you any way He wishes.

Comment: True indeed, thank you for considering the question brother, Shalom

Comment: @eliyah sure. check out this audio for an interesting discussion on this http://dafyomireview.com/audio/m04-3_flaws_of_man_and_role_of_jews.mp3 Rabbi Milevsky there says that Gd doesnt want him to eat of the fruit but there is another etz chaim which He wants him to eat from.

Comment: What if Adam did eat of it and not Eve  ? So what?

Comment: The Rambam sees the tree of good and evil to really represent knowledge. From truth and falsehood. Eve ate the apple. I do not think G-d would manipulate our minds, but I think you answered this well.