# Has anyone ever eaten from the Tree of Life?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, creation, adam

Obviously, the Tree of Knowledge was eaten from by Adam and Chava, but is there any evidence or sources that discuss the Tree of Life?

Comment: Proverbs 3:18...

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50574 & https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26631

Answer (score 1):

[R. Isaiah of Trani (the Elder)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_di_Trani) takes it for granted that Adam had eaten from the Tree of Life, as God had permitted him to eat from all of the trees except for the Tree of Knowledge.

> ותימה וכי עד עתה לא אכל מעץ החיים והלא הרשה אותו מכל עץ הגן אכול תאכל
>
> This is astounding, for until now did he not eat from the Tree of Life? But was it not permitted to him – "from all the trees of the garden you may eat"?

(Excerpted from [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26631/how-does-the-tree-of-life-work/108501#108501).)

Answer (score 0):

[Based on Mishlei 11:30 - Was the עֵ֤ץ הַֽחַיִּים֙ Ets HaChayim in Bereishit 2:9 a Tsadiq?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/120820)

Etz haChayim is the Torah.  We should be eating it from it every day.

- "..and live by them" (Lev. 18:5)
- "She is the tree of life to those who hold by her.." (Prov. 3:18)