# What does "the tree of life" mean when G-d decides on life solely?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, hashkafah-philosophy, theology, parashat-bereishit

My question is maybe an elaboration on this question "[How does the tree of life work?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26631/how-does-the-tree-of-life-work):

The Gemmorah says that G-d decides exclusively on a person’s lifespan. But the Torah says that G-d Himself is frightened by the idea that Adam could eat from the tree of life and become immortal.

So says for example Ramban [ibid](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.3.22?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&with=Ramban&lang2=he):

> רצה הקב"ה שתתקיים גזירתו במיתת האדם **ואם יאכל מעץ החיים שנברא לתת לאוכליו חיי עולם תבטל הגזרה** או שלא ימות כלל או שלא יבא יומו בעת הנגזר עליו ועל תולדותיו

How this contradiction is resolved?

Comment: Something "created to grant immortality" would require a fundamental change in nature to override its effect, so better a minor intervention in nature than a major one. I presume that's why you reference a Gemora about G-d's control over lifespan (where?) rather than the general idea of G-d's omnipotence, but I don't think that it removes the basic thrust of the answer.

Comment: @AKA I think the opposite - the creation of "something to grant immortality" contradicts G-d's exclusive right to decide.

Comment: Not really - exclusive unless eaten from the tree... "Cold and heat" are not biydei shamayim either.

Comment: Rambam thinks the tree of life did not denote good and evil but from right from wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan Don't you mean the aitz hada'as

Comment: @sabbahillel This comes from the Moreh Nevukhim.

Comment: The story is clearly based on / responding to the Epic of Gilgamesh, in which the gods were not considered as omnipotent as the later monotheistic one.

Comment: @nbubis It might be based on anything, but it is expected to be consistent with the rest of its teachings, IMHO.